# ngOptions ordering and selecting objects in array

Tags: arrays, drop-down-menu, angularjs, ng-options

I have a set of options in my controller that looks like this:

```
$scope.options = [
    {one: 'ONE'},
    {two: 'TWO'},
    {three: 'THREE'}
];
```

My view looks like the following currently looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="goal in objectives">
   ...
  <select ng-model="goal.choices" ng-options="value for (key, value) in options">  </select>
   ...
</div>
```

PROBLEM: the resulting dropdown is not sorted by obj occurence in array rather by alpha of each objects key AND there is no default option selected, i want the dropdown to default to 'one' not ''

What is the ng-options expression need to make this work?????

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `$scope.options` array isn't usable in `ngOptions` because you have an array of three entirely different objects (one has a `one` property, another a `two` property, and the last a `three` property).  If you want the `select` to default to `$scope.choices[0]`, then `goal.choices` needs to be set to `$scope.options[0]`.

I had to make some guesses here, because you didn't include what `$scope.objectives` was, but I can imagine you were going for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/A5KkM/

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="x">
    <div ng-repeat="goal in objectives">{{goal.choice}}
        <select ng-model="goal.choice" ng-options="o.name for o in options"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function x($scope) {
    $scope.options = [{
        name: 'ONE'
    }, {
        name: 'TWO'
    }, {
        name: 'THREE'
    }];

    $scope.objectives = [{ choice: $scope.options[0] }, { choice: $scope.options[1] }];
}
```